# How do handle multi-language search in pgsql

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, search, multilingual

We are required to create a search that can handle multi-language inputs.
The reason being is that we are working with a name field and any language is allowed. You can see an illustrative example bellow:

### Case 1

```
tbl_users

+---+---------+
|id |  value  |
+---+---------+
| 1 | Chris   |
| 2 | Крис    |
| 3 | Χρήστος |
| 4 | Akçay   |
+---+---------+
```

In the table above we have the occurrences of the same name in the first 3 rows however all 3 are in different alphabets (latin, greek, cyrillic) and then in the 4th a latin with extra characters (another example would be with a german ö etc)

The aim of the search is to be able to handle all these but also with latin input.
i.e

```
input: Kris  -> should result in Крис   
input: Akcay -> should result in Akçay
```

As we will be utilizing postgres I was looking into `tsvector` and `tsquery` however the localization features of these functions focus on lexicon weights (removing the word `the` etc) and not the characters/words.

The above example might be a bit far fetched however we have a simpler one based on the following

### Case 2

```
tbl_place

+---+---------+
|id |  value  |
+---+---------+
| 1 | кафе    |
| 2 | Cafe    |
| 3 | café    |
+---+---------+
```

Here the input of the word `cafe` should optimistically result all 3 but if not at least the last 2 `cafe` and `café`.

### Current Solution

My assumption is that without proper translation (which in names can be almost impossible) the only other approach is to use character maps i.e to replace in the input the German `ß` into `ss` and have a resulting table:

```
tbl_value

+---+---------+------------------+
|id |  value  | normalized_value |
+---+---------+------------------+
| 1 | vögel   | voegel           |
| 2 | straße  | strasse          |
+---+---------+------------------+
```

This takes a normalization approach however even this has it's issues.
In german the character `ö` is equivelant to `oe` however an input of `vogel` by just ommiting the umlaut should be acceptable.

## Proposals

As per my current solution we will be building multiple mappings to match every input we can think of. However I am doubting the efficiency, output and also scalability of this approach.

Are there other solutions that can help us?
Be it, software, logical code solution, configurations of localizations/extra dictionaries in postgres etc etc.

Comment: Will you also want to support subtle misspellings? E.g. find "Meyer" when searching for "Meier"?

Comment: **If** you want to follow the normalization approach, you might be interested in [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/unaccent.html)

Comment: For now misspellings no, however what would be the added complexity of that? @blubb I am reading now about unaccent thanks!

Comment: I am asking about misspellings because that would constitute a tipping point where I would definitely go with ElasticSearch instead of a RDBMS. So if you'd like to keep that option open without re-implementing large parts of what ElasticSearch delivers out of the box, I would recommend ElasticSearch for the job. Otherwise you might get by using Postgres' `unaccent` and a few custum tweaks.

Comment: @blubb I see. Ye misspellings is unlikely to be needed and as I want to keep the amount of services we use to a minimum I will try with postgres. What I am thinking now is if it would be worth to apply the unaccent via code or via sql. The dictionary can be the same but maybe better performance if its already done via code